# PhoneGap/Cordova not displaying fonts until I click on page

Tags: android, cordova, fonts, phonegap-plugins

I have a PhoneGap app which immediately does a window.location = 'http://example.com' and then continues to work from the web site. It works great... except that on Android my fonts are behaving strangely. I am using a couple of web fonts, loaded using:

```
<link href="http://webfontpath/blah.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This works great when I look at the site on the web, and when I load it in the PhoneGap app on iPhone. On Android, however, characters in both of these fonts just show up blank. At least, they do until I click on one of my buttons, at which point the fonts magically spring into view and remain there through the rest of the time the user is in the app.

I originally thought it was a CORS problem but I've checked and I do already have access origin set to "*" in confg.xml. Also, if it was a security thing, it doesn't really make sense them popping up when I click on the page.

I have also tried copying one of these fonts to a folder on my own site and referring to it there instead - the behaviour remains the same.

I was thinking that maybe PhoneGap is displaying the page to me before the fonts have actually loaded, so I added some Javascript to refresh the page after five seconds, but that doesn't update the fonts. Really it seems like I actually have to click a button on the screen.

I know this all sounds very odd but, well, it is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definite answer, but maybe a possible workaround.

perhaps the render of :before and :after is before the font is ready, in which case it renders blank. If you force a redraw it should fix, which it does when you click. Try the below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $style;
  $style = $('<style type="text/css">:before,:after{content:none !important}</style>');
  $('head').append($style);
  return setTimeout((function() {
    return $style.remove();
  }), 0);
});
```